# instant values for d3 enter selection and transitioned for update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to avoid repeating code for the enter and update selections in d3. I have successfully used `merge` to get the right selection of all items that are present with the new data (after I have used `append` to add the new ones). Now I want to set some attributes such as `r`, `cy` and `cx`. I can do that on the merged selection but if I put them behind a `transition` the items that are just appearing animate in from 0,0 and I want them to just appear in the right place.

What I'm hoping for is some way to write all the attribute setting lines into one function and one time pass in the enter() selection and the next time pass in the transitioned merge so that I only have to write the lines for setting `cx` once. Here's what I have already followed by my guess at pseudo code

```
 const valueCircles = this.chartGroup.selectAll('.valueCircle')
        .data(values);

    valueCircles.enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('stroke-width', '1px')
        .attr('stroke', '#ffffff')
        .attr('opacity', '1')
        .attr('class', 'dots valueCircle')
        .merge(valueCircles)
        .transition()
        .duration(100)
        .attr('r', (d) => {
            if (d.y < 0.5 ) {
                return 5;
            } else {
                return 15;
            }
        })
        .attr('cx', (d) => {
            return timescale(new Date(d.x));
        })
        .attr('cy', (d) => {
                return valueScale(d.y)
        })
```

This is what I think I want to achieve

```
function setTheDynamicValues(aSelection) {
    aSelection
        .attr('cx', (d) => {
            return timescale(new Date(d.x));
        })
        .attr('cy', (d) => {
                return valueScale(d.y)
        })
}

function updateGraph(newData) {
   const valueCircles = this.chartGroup.selectAll('.valueCircle')
        .data(newData);

   setTheDynamicValues(valueCircles.enter());
   setTheDynamicValues(valueCircles.transition().duration(100));
}
```

Another way of describing this would be to make the duration of the transition 0 for the entering elements and 100 for existing elements so that new ones appear correct and existing ones have a visible transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, D3 selections are immutable: that `merge` of yours is not doing anything. This would be the proper pattern:

```
//here, pay attention to "let" instead of const
let valueCircles = this.chartGroup.selectAll('.valueCircle')
    .data(values);

//our enter selection is called "valuesCirclesEnter"
const valueCirclesEnter = valueCircles.enter()
    .append('circle')
    etc...

//now, you merge the selections
valueCircles = valueCirclesEnter.merge(valueCircles);
```

From that point on, `valueCircles` contains both your updating and entering elements.

Now, back to your question:

An idiomatic D3 indeed has a lot of repetition, and that's a point lots of people complain about D3. But we can avoid some repetition with methods like `selection.call`. Also, since you want a transition for the update selection but none for the enter selection, you can simply drop the `merge`.

Here is a basic exemple, using a bit of your code:

```js
const data1 = [{
  x: 100,
  y: 100
}, {
  x: 230,
  y: 20
}];
const data2 = [{
  x: 10,
  y: 10
}, {
  x: 50,
  y: 120
}, {
  x: 190,
  y: 100
}, {
  x: 140,
  y: 30
}, {
  x: 270,
  y: 140
}];
const svg = d3.select("svg");
draw(data1);
setTimeout(() => draw(data2), 1000);

function draw(values) {
  const valueCircles = svg.selectAll('.valueCircle')
    .data(values);

  valueCircles.enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr("class", "valueCircle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .call(positionCircles);

  valueCircles.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .call(positionCircles)
};

function positionCircles(selection) {
  selection.attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

In the snippet above, I'm positioning both the enter and update selections using a function called `positionCircles`; however, while for the enter selection I'm passing a simple selection, for the update selection I'm passing a transitioning selection. But the function is the same:

```
function positionCircles(selection) {
  selection.attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y)
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works great. As far as I can tell the chaining effect of d3 means the .merge I used is doing the same thing you've done without creating valueCirclesEnter.

Comment: What I meant is that your `merge` is not doing anything regarding your selection: it's still the same. Naming selections is a good practice for reusing them, but you can see that in my snippet there is no `valueCirclesEnter`. Therefore, what I'm doing at the beginning of the answer is just showing in a verbose way how to properly merge named selections and using them (by their names) later.

Comment: I think your `valueCirclesEnter` way would be of benefit if I was going to use valueCircles again later, but I've just chained them together so the `.transition()` which follows the `merge()` in my code is operating on both the new and the existing data points (which is not what I wanted, your `call()` is the solution I needed)